# How does a Broadcastreceiver work?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm new to Android and want to know how it works. Specifically, does each broadcastreceiver run in a separate thread ?

If not so, say a computationally intensive task is going on outside the receiver and simultaneously in a separate application, broadcasts are being sent for the receiver. Then, does the receiver have some sort of queue to manage incoming requests when the intensive task gets over ? Or does it ignore the requests ?

To be more specific, I'm writing an application which sends data to a server, gets a response and monitors battery life. I'm a bit skeptical about the broadcastreceiver monitoring battery life executes the moment it's sent an intent about battery level changed.

Thanks for the input in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specifically, does each broadcastreceiver run in a separate thread ?

No. `onReceive()` is always called on the process' main application thread.

> Then, does the receiver have some sort of queue to manage incoming requests when the intensive task gets over ?

Your "computationally intensive task" should not be running on the main application thread and therefore should not interfere with the timely receipt of broadcasts.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had another question too. The computationally intensive task is running inside another broadcast receiver. How do I start this receiver in a new thread ?

Comment: @user2103008: "The computationally intensive task is running inside another broadcast receiver." -- that is not a good idea. "How do I start this receiver in a new thread ?" -- that is not possible. Have the receiver delegate the "computationally intensive task" to an `Service` that can have a background thread, such as an `IntentService`

Comment: @CommonsWare - sir , what is the maximum time a receiver can do work? i have read that if the process is long and if executed in the receiver the app would give an ANR and that occurs when an app does not respond in 5seconds, can we therefore say that the max time a receiver can do a process is 5 seconds? yes, i understand we have services for the long processes but then just wanted to know the duration :).

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille: "what is the maximum time a receiver can do work?" -- to not freeze your foreground UI (if you happen to be in the foreground), `onReceive()` should return in under one millisecond. In other words, `onReceive()` is no different than any other method of yours that is called on the main application thread (e.g., `getView()` of a `ListAdapter`).

Comment: under 1millisecond? wow thats so super quick.. :).. thats why all that most of the receivers do is simply receive an action such as battery low and all isn't it? Thanks for the response :). il lock it in my memory too.

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tatRatatouille: A manifest-registered receiver will usually delegate longer work to an `IntentService`, possibly using one of the "wakeful" patterns (`WakefulBroadcastReceiver` or my `WakefulIntentService`).